# How do I use whereYear inside filter Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have a collection that I am trying to filter on created_at year.  Laravel 5.3.  I am trying to use whereYear inside my filter but it's sqwaking that the method is undefined.  How do I define it?  Or is there a better way?

```
      $datas = Campaign::all();

      if($request->year) {
         $value = $request->year;
         $datas = $datas->filter(function($data) use ($value) {
             return $data->created_at->whereYear($value);
         });
       }
```

Comment: whereYear will not work because Eloquent will search for a year field in the table..you will have to use standard SQL query i guess

Comment: where year works on a time stamp field and does not require a "year field". Its looking for a date like "2016" only RushVan

"->whereYear('created_at', '2016')" will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this more compact:

So in your Controller you can do:

```
$datas = ($request->year)
       ? Campaign::inYear($request->year)->get()
       : Campaign::all();
```

The advantage is, that you **get only the record that you need** from the DB, and don't have to do any kind of filter on a Collection. This will also **increaser your performance** a little bit.

In your Campaign Model you add on `inYear` scope that is than **reusable**:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Campaign extends Model
{
    public function scopeInYear($query, $year)
    {
        return $query->whereBetween('created_at', [
            Carbon::create($year)->startOfYear(),
            Carbon::create($year)->endOfYear(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Have never used the ? : if else like that before.  Thanks!  Small typo, needs to be create not crate.  Please correct and I'll mark as answer.

Answer (score 2):

In laravel `created_at` is an instance of Carbon so :

```
$datas = Campaign::all();

if($request->year) {
    $value = $request->year;
    $datas = $datas->filter(function($data) use ($value) {
        return $data->created_at->year == $value;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`whereYear(...)` is shorthand for `where('year', ...)` in Laravel, but you want to be searching against `created_at`, so that's not going to work. Something like this should do the trick, and reduce the number of records you have to fetch from the DB as well:

```
// better to let the database handle the search
// than fetching all records and filtering the collection
$query = Campaign::query();

if($request->year) {
    // be sure to validate $request->year somewhere, for obvious reasons...
    $query->whereBetween('created_at', $request->year . '-01-01 00:00:00', $request->year . '-12-31 23:59:59')
}

return $query->get();
```